# Даны натуральные числа от (-N) до N. Найти все трехзначные числа, у которых четные сотни. (N <1000)

Tags: c++

Правильно сделано или надо еще одно число водить , я просто понять немогу  Даны натуральные числа от (-N) до N. Найти все трехзначные числа, у которых четные сотни. (N <1000)

---

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> using namespace std;
> bool check(int k){
>    return ((k / 10) % 10) % 2 == 0;
> }
> int main() {
>    int n;
>    cin >> n;
>    if(n < 0) n *= -1;
>    for(int i = 100; i <= n; i++)
>        if(check(i))
>            cout << i << "\n";
> }
> ```

Comment: Натуральных отрицательных чисел не бывает. Вы уверены что с формулировкой задачи порядок?

Comment: Может быть так: "даны натуральные числа не более `abs(N)`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вы неверно досаете сотни из числа.
2. Вы бежите не от `-n`, а от `100`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool check(int k){
    return !((k/100)%10 % 2);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    if(n<0) n *= -1;
    for(int k=-n+1; k<n; ++k)
        if(check(k)) 
            cout << k << ' ';
}
```

P.S. Теперь выводит только 3х-значные.
Спасибо [@Stanislav Volodarskiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/416121/stanislav-volodarskiy) за `%10 %2 -> %2`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool check(int k){
    return (k/100) ? !((k/100) % 2) : 0;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    if(n<0) n *= -1;
    for(int k=-n+1; k<n; ++k)
        if(check(k)) 
            cout << k << ' ';
}
```

Comment: Еще вопрос одно должно значение с клавиатуры водится или два , вот я понять по задаче немогу?

Comment: @bonitok381 судя по тому, что в задании от `-n` до `n` - одно.

Comment: Хорошо ,спасибо

Comment: @bonitok381 отметьте ответ галочкой, если он помог.

Comment: `%10 % 2` -> `% 2`.

Comment: Ваш код выведет не только трёхзначные числа.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy в каком плане ? Если ввести n>1000, то да. Но n<1000 это ограничение пользовательского ввода, насколько я понимаю вроде того, что дают на олимпиадах и подобных занятиях.

Comment: В задаче просят вывести только трёхзначные числа. Ваш код выведет `0`, `10`, `99`. Все они нетрёхзначные.